# Align Center Menu Item text in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Using following code

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:title="@string/mainMenu"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</item>
```

I have a style defined as

```
<style name="MenuTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">6F6B6B</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
```

But the menu text still is not in the middle. How to make it center in middle?

Answer (score 15):

You can center-align the menu items dynamically using `SpannableString` in your activity:

```
int positionOfMenuItem = 0; //or any other postion
MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsItemTitle);

s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

item.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: Note: this just center on horizontal

Comment: @ParthPatel in your onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is via setting theme

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar.NavigationViewPadding"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/inverse_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/inverse_color"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_navigation"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_home_nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

In your styles

```
    <style name="ThemeToolbar.NavigationViewPadding">
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">50dp</item>
    </style>
```

[image: How it looks like]

Answer (score 1):

I used @Mahm00d's way, that worked perfectly, but I found another way to solve the problem. It is to add `\t` before the String. If the space isn't enough, I can add more.

Because Chinese words are one by one, the length of the item is same.