# PopupMenu - how to?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I am beginner in android and try to make an app that popup a menu when imageView is clicked. Actually it works but popup at right side and I want to be at center.
      So, I searched for it on web and come across ListPopupWindow, PopupWindow classes. I tried various methods of this classes as per my knowledge/ability but I am not able to achieve this.
      Guide me to do that. Here is my code

```
imageview setonclickListener(new View.onclickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view){
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Info4 Activity.this, imageview1);
        Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) (subjects.size()); i++) {
            val = subjects.get((int) (i));
            menu.add(val);
        }
        popup.show();
    }
});
```

[image: popup menu]

Comment: You can use Dialogs too if you want it in the center.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19344297/7734566

Answer (score 0):

**PopupMenu**:

The popup will appear below the **anchor** if there is room, or above it if there is not. In your situation the anchor is `imageView`, so you can not center the popup in screen.

**PopupWindow**:

Try this:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);// here v is any View only needed for WindowToken
        }
    });
```

**Other better ways:**

May be you could be think about using [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment), which is customizable and flexible.